# UITextView keeping cursor blinking while it's not first responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to keep the cursor blinking when UITextView is not first responder?
Or is there any other way to put another view on top of keyboard while it's first responder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can keep the cursor blinking without it being firstResponder, but there is [a tutorial here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) which shows you how to put a view over the keyboard.